# How to make a "perfect" hover using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

Well, I've almost achieved what I was aiming for. There's an image and when hovered, a div fades over with text and background. The problem is when the user hovers the "new" div (text and background).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
        <div class="admin">
            <div class="admin-img">
                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/g/210/210/abstract" />
            </div>
            <div class="admin-txt">
                <h2>Name</h2>
                <p>Job description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="admin">
            <div class="admin-img">
                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/g/210/210/nature" />
            </div>
            <div class="admin-txt">
                <h2>Name</h2>
                <p>Job description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="admin">
            <div class="admin-img">
                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/g/210/210/sports" />
            </div>
            <div class="admin-txt">
                <h2>Name</h2>
                <p>Job description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="other">
            <div class="other-img">
                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/g/100/100/city" />
            </div>
            <div class="other-txt">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <p>Job description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="other">
            <div class="other-img">
                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/g/100/100/nightlife" />
            </div>
            <div class="other-txt">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <p>Job description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="other">
            <div class="other-img">
                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/g/100/100/people" />
            </div>
            <div class="other-txt">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <p>Job description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="other">
            <div class="other-img">
                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/g/100/100/food" />
            </div>
            <div class="other-txt">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <p>Job description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="other">
            <div class="other-img">
                <img src="http://lorempixum.com/g/100/100/animals" />
            </div>
            <div class="other-txt">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <p>Job description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the jQuery I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.admin-img").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).siblings('.admin-txt').stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).siblings('.admin-txt').stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
        });
    $("div.other-img").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).siblings('.other-txt').stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).siblings('.other-txt').stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
        }); 
});
```

How can I make it better?
And, on small images, how can I make the background cover the whole image?

Thanks in advance,
Dani.

Comment: yea this is a classic problem. When you go over the div you are overlaying it is no hovering on the picture! You going to have to detect if they enter your overlay div and stop the hover out.. or catch it somehow..or somehow tell thebroser that the overlay caption is part of the image and hover shoudl stay applied. i beleive it can be done using classes.. i cant remember now

Comment: @ppumkin: Just as I've described in my answer yet somehow this merits a downvote. This is what I hate about SO anonymity.

Comment: @Brian Tell me about it! what about answering correctly 30 minutes before mr 15k and he gets the correct answer! Ill upvote you man to balnce it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/p8gWf/

Changes made on the javascript portion.

Comment: Simpler than the other answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've used the hover toggle on the parent div. Once you hover over the child div your parent looses focus and therefore fires the unhover event.

You should do a check in your unhover event to determine whether you've moved the cursor into the child and cancel the event if this is the case.

Comment: Wasn't me! I'm trying to find a solution for this following your & ppumkin "directions".

Comment: I agree with you, Brian Scott, I get really frustrated when down-voters leave no explanations.  I think the SE FAQs recommend it, don't they?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to simply position your div and make it opacity = 0. Then, you assign the hover to the overlaid div and fade it to 100% opacity. No more hover ambiguity.